# "error executing OcrAction" while using OCR in Workfusion RPA Express.

Tags: ocr, workfusion

I am getting the below error "error executing OcrAction", while reading text from a pdf using OCR in Workfusion RPA Express.

Error executing OcrAction
  com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.PlaybackException: Error executing TemplateAction[templateName=OcrAction.ftl,id=11,name=Optional[OcrAction],parent=-3,nextSibling=12,arguments=ActionArguments[varName=[address],imageName=[C:\Users\pandas\workfusion-workspace\rpae_project\Untitled-20\1531908870651-anchor-1531908870677.apng],fullImageName=[1531908870651.png],xsi:type=[recorder:OcrAction, recorder:OcrAction],pollingInterval=[300],active=[true],type=[CONTROL],offsetX=[9],offsetY=[46],delay=[0],width=[165],actionDetails=[(to 'address' rectangle 165 x 20)],height=[20],awaitTimeout=[5000]]]
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.flow.StandardControlFlow.execute(StandardControlFlow.java:54)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.action.template.TemplateAction.execute(TemplateAction.java:30)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.action.template.TemplateAction.execute(TemplateAction.java:17)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.player.ActionPlayer.next(ActionPlayer.java:53)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.player.PlaybackLogic.playNextAction(PlaybackLogic.java:153)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.player.PlaybackLogic.run(PlaybackLogic.java:113)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Image does not found : 1531908870651-anchor-1531908870677.apng
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '9.0.0.1', revision: 'e3a0fd7071', time: '2018-05-11T11:35:20.018Z'
System info: host: 'CIBL273113', ip: '10.5.58.158', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: com.freedomoss.crowdcontrol.webharvest.selenium.wrapper.RemoteDriverWrapper
Capabilities [{imageSimilarityThreshold=0.8, extra.executor.id={Name=RPA Recorder}, CLOSE_ALL_WINDOWS=false, browserName=universal, javascriptEnabled=true, extra.capabilities.context={"browserType":"universal","startInPrivate":false,"blockImages":false,"maximizeOnStartup":false,"customCapabilities":{"platform":"WINDOWS","javascriptEnabled":true,"SEARCH_ALL_WINDOWS":true,"CLOSE_ALL_WINDOWS":false,"imageSimilarityThreshold":"0.8"},"executorId":{"Name":"RPA Recorder"}}, platformName=WINDOWS, SEARCH_ALL_WINDOWS=true, platform=WINDOWS}]
Session ID: 7363967d-bea5-4e20-b0f6-73fbf34e0cc6
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:41)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:82)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:656)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:592)
      at com.workfusion.rpa.helpers.RPA.executeScript(RPA.java:864)
      at com.workfusion.rpa.helpers.RPA.executeGroovyScript(RPA.java:930)
      at com.workfusion.rpa.helpers.ImageElement.findImageRectangle(ImageElement.java:183)
      at com.workfusion.rpa.helpers.ImageElement.getRect(ImageElement.java:86)
      at com.workfusion.rpa.helpers.UiElement.getRect(UiElement.java:1025)
      at org.openqa.selenium.WebElement$getRect.call(Unknown Source)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
      at Script12.run(Script12.groovy:5)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.shell.GroovyShellWrapper.executeScript(GroovyShellWrapper.java:90)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.player.PlaybackContext.executeScript(PlaybackContext.java:65)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.action.template.TemplateAction.executeBehavior(TemplateAction.java:35)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.flow.StandardControlFlow.execute(StandardControlFlow.java:46)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.action.template.TemplateAction.execute(TemplateAction.java:30)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.action.template.TemplateAction.execute(TemplateAction.java:17)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.player.ActionPlayer.next(ActionPlayer.java:53)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.player.PlaybackLogic.playNextAction(PlaybackLogic.java:153)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.player.PlaybackLogic.run(PlaybackLogic.java:113)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Image does not found : 1531908870651-anchor-1531908870677.apng
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:84)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
      at Script1$1.call(Script1.groovy:12)
      at Script1$1.call(Script1.groovy)
      at com.workfusion.common.utils.SynchUtils.withFocusLock(SynchUtils.java:47)
      at com.workfusion.common.utils.SynchUtils$withFocusLock.call(Unknown Source)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
      at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:5)
      at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:585)
      at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:623)
      at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:594)
      at com.workfusion.autoit.driver.AutoItDriver.executeGroovyScript(AutoItDriver.java:243)
      at com.workfusion.autoit.driver.AutoItDriver.executeScript(AutoItDriver.java:211)
      at com.workfusion.autoit.driver.AutoItDriver.executeScript(AutoItDriver.java:187)
      at com.workfusion.universal.driver.UniversalDriver.executeScript(UniversalDriver.java:149)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ExecuteScript.call(ExecuteScript.java:54)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.WebDriverHandler.handle(WebDriverHandler.java:41)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:133)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:203)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.InMemorySession.execute(InMemorySession.java:98)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.lambda$handle$0(WebDriverServlet.java:231)
      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Please check your server profile setting with OCR configuration. If its blank then please reinstall workfusion studio after checking system requirement of it.

Comment: Hi Vishal,  Thanks for the response. I check the server profile setting with OCR configuration on my machine and it's not blank. Please can you help me what should be done further.

Answer (score 1):

Your root cause is in your exception:

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Image does not found : 1531908870651-anchor-1531908870677.apng
```

It means in OCR action your are using an anchor image and it was not found in the document you are trying to OCR